# How to streaming video conferencing using webRTC

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, webrtc

I am creating a simple video conferencing application using webRTC.

[Find source code here](http://pastebin.com/npda7vMa)

[image]

When I click on the "Setup New Meeting" button, then video streaming start and show new hyperlink like:

[image]

When I click on it a new tab opens with video streaming in this tab and both tabs capture video and in both tabs video conferencing is working.

See the below image:

[image]

In this image you'll the the list of cameras attached to a user's computer. I would like to do the following:

- When I select any camera from the list it will be load in the
  appropriate `<Section>`
- When I click on `<Camera 1>` it will be load in Local Media Stream of user side and other side it will display in Remote Media stream
- When I click on `<Camera 2>` it will be load in Local Media Stream of user side and  other side it will display in Remote Media stream

What is the best way to go about achieving this?

Comment: Have you attached the multiple cameras and you would like to see each camera view in your Video tag when click right?

Comment: Both camera attached in your system or 
One camera from your Local machine
and Second from another's Machine?